# Using unity classes outside of unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I like unity's rigid body transformation functions and I need them in a C# application that has nothing to do with unity. How can I use the [Quaternion class](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html) outside of unity?

I've seen [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityasaLibrary.html) but I'm not sure if it applies to me since I'm still using C#.

Comment: Yes..as the docs say so long as your app is Android, iOS or UWP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much of Unity's functionality is actually written in C++ and is just exposed in C# as an internal call. This is Quaternion.Slerp for example:

```cs
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
private static extern void Slerp_Injected(ref Quaternion a, ref Quaternion b, float t, out Quaternion ret);

[FreeFunction("QuaternionScripting::Slerp", IsThreadSafe = true)]
public static Quaternion Slerp(Quaternion a, Quaternion b, float t)
{
    Slerp_Injected(ref a, ref b, t, out var ret);
    return ret;
}
```

So, it depends which classes you want to use as you'd have to find a pure C# implementation of each - your regular C# application is not going to be able to call internal C++ Unity functionality if not inside Unity.

Fortunately if it's transform related functionality you're after, there is a built in implementation of `Quaternion` and `Vector3` in the `System.Numerics` namespace of C# which has much of the same functionality as what is in Unity which might give you what you're after:

```cs
using System.Numerics;


var axis = Vector3.UnitX;
var angle = 2f; // This is in radians
Quaternion q = Quaternion.CreateFromAxisAngle(rotAxis, rotAngle);
```